# How to get "double donut" chart in google sheet with script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, charts, google-visualization

Libre Office has a very applicable type of charts "Donut" with double ring.
[image: Double donut chart]

I want to get some similar chart in my google sheet

[image: Table example]

Any ideas how to get it better?

Answer (score 2):

Google Sheets has 3 pie types:

- Pie chart
- Doughnut chart
- 3D Pie chart

Go to menu: **Insert > Chart > Chart type > Doughnut chart**

[image]

As you can see there are no double pies currently.

But there is a **workaround** to get double pie chart.

[image]

### Workaround

1. Select your data
2. Insert a Doughnut chart (Insert > Chart > Chart type > Doughnut chart)
3. Go to Customise tab in Chart editor
4. In Chart style > Background colour > select none
5. Tick on 3D
6. In Pie chart > select Doughnut hole 75%
7. Do the same for the inner pie but Doughnut hole with 25%

As you can see, it is doable.
You can adapt it with apps script by using [Charts Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts), in special [Class PieChartBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/pie-chart-builder)

I strongly recommend you to take a look on :

[Fundamentals of Apps Script with Google Sheets #5: Chart and Present Data in Slides](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/apps-script-fundamentals-5/#0)

Good luck